# Is background: no-repeat; needed when you have a fixed sized image?

Tags: html, css

Is `background: no-repeat;` needed when you have a fixed image?

I read that, when put any background image, it's getting repeated by default.

Even when you don't see it on the screen, is it sill getting repeated then, even on a fixed image?

Do you need to specify no-repeat regardless?

The image size is 180 x 180.

```html
<style>
      #playButton4 {
        border: 3px solid #0059dd;
        width: 260px;
        height: 194px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: black;
      }

      .img2 {
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        margin: 7px 40px;
      }

    </style>

    <div id="playButton4" onclick="">

      <div class="img2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-repeat` property is relevant whenever the size of the element exceeds the size of `background-image`. If this ***never*** happens to your element, specifying `background-repeat` is dead code.

If, under any circumstance, your element might become larger than the `background-image` (on either direction) and you don't want the image repeated, you should leave it in.

---

As a side note, `background` is a shorthand property which includes `background-repeat`, thus:

```
background: url(https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png) no-repeat;
```

being an exact equivalent of

```
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png);
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
```

, which reduces your *"dead code"* to only 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need it to avoid repeated image, Your image does not repeat because you set your with same with your image resolution, How if you set your width 100% and not using `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, You will get repeated image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's best to use  ,`no-repeat` unless you want to tile your background images to make background patterns or make background responsive.

Refer: https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/best-practices-for-background-images-your-getting-started-guide/

In your case, you need not use `no-repeat` as you have given a fixed dimension(same as the image dimension) to your container `<div>` . Later, If you wish to change(increase) the dimensions of the container dynamically to make it responsive, then you would definitely need `no-repeat` .